# PHP ignores new paragraphs when pulling data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this string in my mysql db
"The most effective ways of bringing it about.
 Ideas are not set in stone."
Now when PHP pulls the data from db it return this
`education but also one of the most effective ways of bringing it about. Ideas`
But i want it to add new paragraph like in mysql,i don't want it in one line.

Comment: If you have newlines (`\r\n, \n`) in your code, then you need to convert them to HTML. [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is a good function

Comment: @aynber`nl2br()` helped. Thanks!